# Scene is too dark and cant fix it

Tags: modeling, light, scene

Im having a problem with this bedroom scene I have setup where the scene is extremely dark and Im not sure what to do about it. It looks extremely gloomy compared to the video im following along with. If someone could take a look at it, it would be greatly appreciated. A link to the video im following and the file are below.

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUf9VltV4Cc)

[Blender file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hmis48iczwl7p02/Bedroom.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Please don't make the question depend exclusively on a link or users watching some video and trying to deduct where you strayed from it. Add information on your project and show the settings you are using. Did you try increasing the power for your lights? Are you using any clamping?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the bad question, however after tinkering with it for about an hour I found my solution. I added an RGB curve between my HDRi and the background node. Decreasing the blue value and increasing the red value got the desired effect as well as turning down the "c" value.